# MySQL reporting syntax errors when inserting .png images as BLOB

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am developing a character editor within a game, using PHP to communicate Unity with a MySQL database.

After players edit their characters, I update the DB with the new texture for the character and its unique id. I gather those parameters from Unity's C# like this:

```
string idAlumno = GameManager.Instance.usuario.Id.ToString();
string idAvatar = args.json["id"];
BinaryDataField binary = new BinaryDataField();
binary.fieldName = "imagenAvatar";
binary.contents = character.finalTexture.EncodeToPNG();
```

Then, I send a request with those `idAlumno`, `idAvatar`, and `binary` to a PHP file that handles the interaction with the database like this:

```
<?php
include ('conexion.php');

$idAlumno = $_POST['idAlumno'];
$idAvatar = $_POST['idAvatar'];
$imagenAvatar = file_get_contents($_FILES['imagenAvatar']['tmp_name']);

$query = "UPDATE alumnos SET idAvatar = {$idAvatar}, imagenAvatar = {$imagenAvatar} WHERE idAlumno = {$idAlumno}";

$return = array ();

if ( !$mysqli->query($query) ) {
    die("Error: {$mysqli->errno}; {$mysqli->error}; Query -> {$query}");
}

$return['id'] = $mysqli->insert_id;

echo json_encode($return);
```

This reports:

```
Error: 1064; You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' ' at line 2
```

and the query looks like this:

```
UPDATE alumnos SET idAvatar = 69, imagenAvatar = �PNG  IHDR+� IDATx�y�$�}&��u]]}��=G3�$n�(J$�X���V+i�c-��^{�v��P����6$Y)-I��(�)�$H� ��`L�=}��u���UeuvOY�U�u��Lvfe����^���{�����jA@A@A@A��0Z�y�:A@A@A@A@ "�~ �� �� �� �"h��,MA@A@A@D }@A@A@A@hD�/Y�(�� �� �� �@�� �� �� �� ��� ^�4QA@A@A@��A@A@A@A� @�di� �� �� �� ��� �� �� �@
```

... and a bunch of extra strange-character-populated lines.

This seems odd to me, since I tried editing the blob from PhpMyAdmin and the resulting query looks much more neat:

```
UPDATE `alumnos` SET `imagenAvatar` = 0x89504e470d0a1a0a0000000d4948445200000400000004[...]
```

---

I have tried saving the image returned by

`file_get_contents($_FILES['imagenAvatar']['tmp_name']);`

and it gets saved, and displays, correctly in my hard drive, so this leads me to think there is some kind of problem with how I handle the file before or during the query, but I can't find what it is.

The current collation in my DB is utf8md4_unicode_ci, though I've already tried using simply utf8 with the same or similar results.

---

I've also tried using `addslashes()`, `mysqli::real_escape_string()`, or a combination of them, and even using `fopen()` and `fread()` after saving the temporary file to my hard drive. All of these always lead to the same error

Comment: You should save the images to the server, and use the path to it in your database instead. Storing images in the database it self is not recommended.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Answer (score -1):

See below:

```
$idAlumno = $_POST['idAlumno']; // escape this or cast to int!
$idAvatar = $_POST['idAvatar']; // escape this or cast to int!
$imagenAvatar = file_get_contents($_FILES['imagenAvatar']['tmp_name']);
$imagenAvatar = bin2hex($imagenAvatar);
$query = "UPDATE alumnos SET idAvatar = {$idAvatar}, imagenAvatar = 0x{$imagenAvatar} WHERE idAlumno = {$idAlumno}";
```

Note the `0x` prepended to the hex string.

Unrelated to your question, but perhaps relevant to your project, you may want to re-think storing images in the database. Perhaps you could save them in a directory and store a path instead.

You may also want to switch to using PDO or some other DB library. Either way, make sure every value in a query is either pulled from a whitelist or escaped.

Comment: This completely misses the problem and that problem is **unescaped data**.

Comment: Note the comments in my code: `escape this or cast to int!`. Also note the last sentence in my post: `Either way, make sure every value in a query is either pulled from a whitelist or escaped.` Also note the image is escaped by converting it to hex. What else exactly should I be doing to point the OP in towards sanitizing his inputs?

Comment: It takes a lot longer to write that out than it does to just do it properly, and casting to `int` is not doing it properly. The problem is easily solved with `bind_param`. Switching to hex just side-steps the issue.